# Does the following simultaneous differential equations has an analytical solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm wondering whether the following simultaneous differential equations has an analytical solution?

$$\begin{cases} \cfrac{dx}{dt}=\cfrac{2v}{x^2+v^2} \\ \cfrac{dv}{dt}=\cfrac{-2x}{x^2+v^2} \end{cases}$$

Comment: Yes, it does. What have you tried?

Comment: I just found some instruction for linear simultaneous differential equation case. For non-linear case I had not  found the solution.

Comment: Hint: polar coordinates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
  z &= v+xi \\
  |z|^2 &= v^2+x^2 \\
  \frac{d|z|^2}{dt}  &= 2v \frac{dv}{dt}+2x\frac{dx}{dt} \\
  &= 0 \\
  |z| &= k \\
  \frac{dz}{dt} &= \frac{2(-x+vi)}{v^2+x^2} \\
  &= \frac{2iz}{|z|^2} \\
  &= \frac{2iz}{k^2} \\
  \frac{dz}{z} &= \frac{2i}{k^2} dt \\
  \ln z &= \frac{2it}{k^2}+c \\
  z &= A\exp \left( \frac{2it}{k^2} \right)
  \tag{$c=\ln A$} \\
  &= k\exp \left[ i\left( \frac{2t}{k^2}+\phi \right) \right]
  \tag{$A=ke^{i\phi}$} \\
  v(t) &= k\cos \left( \frac{2t}{k^2}+\phi \right) \\
  x(t) &= k\sin \left( \frac{2t}{k^2}+\phi \right) \\
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Use symbol $y$ in place of $v$ for quicker recognition.

$$ \cfrac{dx}{dt}=\cfrac{2y}{x^2+y^2} ;\cfrac{dy}{dt}=\cfrac{-2x}{x^2+y^2} ;$$

Divide to eliminate parameter $t$

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{-x}{y} , \text { integrate } \to x^2+y^2=c_1^2$$

$$ x = c_1 \cos (t + c_2)  ; y = c_1 \sin (t + c_2);$$

Alternately recognize second order DEs

$$ \ddot x + x=0 \;;\ddot y + y=0\;;$$

Comment: The solution should read $$v+xi=k \exp \left( \frac{2it}{k^2}+\phi \right)$$

Comment: @Narasimham My stupid question: $dy/dt=c_1cos(t+c_2)$ while $-2x/(x^2+y^2)=-cos(t+c_2)/c_1$ if use your solution.

Comment: It's a second order ODE, $$(v',x')=\frac{2(-x,v)}{k^2} \implies (v'',x'')=\frac{2(-x',v')}{k^2}=-\frac{4(v,x)}{k^4}$$

Comment: After you found $x^2+y^2=c_1^2$ you could have parametrized $x(t)=c_1\sin(u(t))$, $y(t)=c_1\cos(u(t))$ and then conclude that $u'(t)=\frac{2}{c_1^2}$, which now is easy to integrate.